# What is main difference between creation of reference vs creation of object?

Tags: c++, object, dictionary, reference, boost-extension

So a while ago I were playing with Boost.Extension example. [They used](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/libs/extension/examples/multiple_inheritance/main_mi.cpp)

```
  std::map<std::string, factory<computer> > computers;
  computers.swap(types.get());
```

But when I started porting project [from bjam to premake to visual studio project 2008](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/wiki/BoostExtensionTutorialsWithPremake) I found out that I can not use method they used for creating map. I always got [Compiler Error C2512](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zkz8dx6%28VS.71%29.aspx) on that line (actually on [line 74 inside Boost.Extension type_map.hpp](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension/type_map.hpp)). So [I used way of creating a link to a map](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/branches/v0.4/Boost.Extension.Tutorial/src/multiple-inheritance_main.cpp):

```
map<string, factory<computer> >& computers(types.get());
```

(they used in [some of there tutorials](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/libs/extension/examples/tutorial_2/)) and it all compiled. I am quite new to C++ and probably do not get alot.

So what is difference between creation of a map from link vs simple creation of a map, in this case and in general?

Update - full error message

> Error 1   error C2512:
>   boost::extensions::basic_type_map::type_map_convertible::type_holder:
>   no appropriate default constructor
>   available c:\users\avesta\downloads\extension-svn-source\boost\extension\type_map.hpp 74  Mltiple-Inheritance

Comment: Does the error message tell you which class is missing a default constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the second case doesn't create a map at all; it creates a reference to a map that already exists. `types` contains a map, and `types.get()` returns a reference to that map, which you use to initialise your own reference. If you modify the map using that reference, then you are modifying the map contained in `types`.

The first case does create an empty map; it then swaps it with the (presumably non-empty) map contained in `types`, leaving `types` empty afterwards. This will require more support from the various classes involved; some might need to be default constructible, swappable, and possibly copyable and/or assignable. The error code seems to indicate that one of the classes needs a public default constructor, but doesn't have one; it might help to diagnose the problem if you include the whole error message.